# JQuery 2.1 - load with class but take only from the inside of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is HTML part:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-body">
        <?php echo $post->body ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var posts = $('.posts'),
    postToggle = posts.find('.post-toggle');

    postToggle.on('click', function(){
        var $this  = $(this),
        postLink   = $this.data('link'),
        postParent = $this.closest('.post'),
        postBody   = postParent.find('.post-body');

        postBody.load(postLink + " .post-body", function(){
            $(this).toggle('fast');
        });
        $this.toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');


        return false;
    });
```

This function is working, but I need the content of the div.post-body, and not the hole div tag (inside is just a plain text). Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Nope, you can't toggle the display of textnodes, just elements, if this is an issue with the tag taking up space, you could toggle visibility instead, that way it stays in the "flow" !

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, just do a `postParent.find('.post-body').html()`

Comment: This would work if I needed text from the current page. In my load function I am looking .post-body from a single post, and this function is fired in page where all posts are listed.